# Netbeans 8.1 how to expose a ejb in restful service

Tags: service, ejb, netbeans-8, restful-architecture

I work with Netbeans 8.1. I want to convert a EJB in restful service.

My EJB is

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package paqueteservicio;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

/**
 *
 * @author Carlota
 */
@Stateless
@Path("/collatz")
public class CollatzResource {
    @GET
    public String collatz(@QueryParam("base")long base){
        int num = (int)base;
        String secuencia = "Inicio"+num+"\n";
        while (num != 1){
            if (num %2 == 0){
                num = num / 2;
            }
            else {
                num = num * 3 + 1;
            }
            secuencia  += num + "\n";
        }
        return secuencia;
    }

}
```

How can I convert this EJB in Restful Service?. Is there any option?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is enable rest in your application:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {
    /* class body intentionally left blank */
}
```